# Input field with unit and step

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to create an input field with unit and step.
I don't mean that unit is positioned next to the input field, and unit needs to be kept when typing inside the input field.
Also, input field allows only values as multiple value of a specific step.
For example, I would like to create an input field which allows only 10Cm, 20Cm, 30Cm, 40Cm, ... (unit: Cm, step: 10).

Please let me know if you have some experience.